# Inno Setup - How can I put a message on the welcome page

Tags: inno-setup

Can I put a message on the Inno Setup Welcome page? I would like something [like this](http://goo.gl/MCfTI)

Comment: Edit your ISL file or add CustomMessage by [CODE] `TLabel.Create(WizardForm)`.

Comment: @RobeN It's considered bad practice to edit the `.isl` file directly as it negatively effects maintainability, and any changes will be wiped out when they're updated.

Comment: @Deanna not if you create your own/personalized version of IS (e.g. custom compile) that you use for large number of installers. You can always create your own ISL file to keep ISS Script clean and tidy.

Comment: @RobeN Then you have an even bigger maintainability problem... Why fork the setup project source code (with all the hassle of compiling it) to avoid adding two lines to the script that would work in the stock version?

Comment: @Deanna - I was a little bit general. I'm not talking about this very case, but the case if you need special functionality, or when you produce great amount of installers with long code section and you want to have exclusive ISL outside of the main script. There is IS Source to use it if you need, not to print and put on the wall :-) In this case - ok, you can override message or create own entry in Code to make it stylized.

Answer (score 17):

You can change the text of the welcome message by overriding the value on the `[Messages]` section:

```
[Messages]
WelcomeLabel2=This will install [name/ver] on your computer.%n%nIt is recommended that you close all other applications and disable any anti virus before continuing.
```

If you want to change the style (colour, size, etc) then you will need to create and position the controls individually in the `InitializeWizard()` event function.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But I still have no idea that how to write a code to change color and word size, any sample code for reference ?

Comment: How to translate such non custom messages? I usually use the [CustomMessages] section, which is translated, but never for preset inno message...

Comment: @Sandburg `en.WelcomeLabel2` I believe (where `en` matches your language's name.)

Answer (score 9):

@Deanna answer is the correct one.

Now, if you also want to change the font colour and format you can do:

```
[Messages]
WelcomeLabel2=This will install [name/ver] on your computer.%n%nIt is recommended that you close all other applications and disable any anti virus before continuing.

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Font.Style := [fsBold]; //Bold
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Font.Color := clRed; // And red colour
end;
```